# Qt - Problema al dibujar sistema de coordenadas cartesianas con QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy tratando de graficar el sistema de coordenadas X e Y. Utilizo un QGraphicsItem. Este graphicsitem, tiene como coordenada superior X e Y...a medida que avanzo hacia la derecha, el X crece y hacia la izquierda el X disminuye, tal cual es lo normal en el sistema de coordenadas.
Ahora bien...mi problema es el eje Y...a medida que yo voy hacia abaja CRECE y deberia DECRECER y cuando subo DECRECE cuando en el sistema de coordenadas deberia CRECER. Se entiende?...dejo la definicion del codigo que tengo...es una porcion...espero se entienda el problema.

```
QPointF centralPoint = QPointF(0, 0);
farmGraph = new FarmGraph(_size, centralPoint);
```

Y la clase FarmGraph, en su boundingRect, que es lo importante de la definicion, es la siguiente:

```
QRectF FarmGraph::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(_centralPoint.x() - (_size/2),
              _centralPoint.y() - (_size/2),
              _size,
              _size);
}
```

Osea...es como si tuviera que "espejar" sobre la coordenada Y para que pueda graficar curvas como corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya le encontré la vuelta googleando un poco y con un ejemplo que encontré. Publico la solucion por si a alguien le sirve y cierro la pregunta. 
La solucion pasa por invertir, por medio de la escala negativa, el eje Y de la siguiente forma:

```
QPointF centralPoint = QPointF(0, 0);
farmGraph = new FarmGraph(_size, centralPoint);
farmGraphi->setTransform(QTransform().scale(1, -1));
```